# How do I add comments to Json.NET output?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is there a way I can automatically add comments to the serialised output from Json.NET?

Ideally, I'd imagine it's something similar to the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonComment("My documentation string")]
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

Or (even better if annotations can be avoided):

```
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// My documentation string
    /// </summary>
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

Tthat would produce:

```js
{
    // My documentation string
    "MyString": "Test"
}
```

The reason that I ask is that we use Json.NET to serialise a configuration file which could be changed by hand later on. I'd like to include documentation in my C# configuration classes and have that reproduced in the JSON to help whoever may have to change the file later.

---

As RoToRa points out below, comments are not technically allowed in the JSON specification (see the handy syntax diagrams at http://www.json.org). However, the features table on the [Json.NET site](http://json.codeplex.com) includes:

> *Supports reading and writing comments*

and `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WriteComment(string)` exists which does output a comment. I'm interested in a neat way of creating the comments rather than using the `JsonTextWriter` directly.

Comment: @JamesNewtonKing is there anything like this planned or available currently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Json.NET JsonSerializer doesn't automatically output comments when serializing. You'll need to write your JSON manually, either using JsonTextWriter or LINQ to JSON if you want comments

Comment: @JamesNewtonKing I've written a small patch to the latest Json.NET to add a `Comment` property to `JsonProperty` (and `JsonPropertyAttribute`). The idea is that during `SerializeMemberInfo` if the `Comment` is not null/empty then it gets written out above the key/value pair in the JSON. Before I go on and complete it, is that something you'd be interested in?

Comment: I'll take a look at it and see how you've done it and whether I think it would be useful to others - http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/patches/upload

Comment: @AdamRodger do you still have the patch? I can't find it online.

Comment: @JamesNewton-King Did anything ever come of this?

Comment: @JamesNewton-King also interested in this.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that JSON as a file format doesn't support comments. One thing you could do - if the application reading the JSON file allows it - is to use additional properties as comments as suggested in this question: [Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-i-comment-a-json-file)

Answer (score 5):

Well there is *something* one can do in order to add a comment to the output, but I would **not** do it except out of truly desperation.

You can write a custom Converter:

```
public class JsonCommentConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly string _comment;
    public JsonCommentConverter(string comment)
    {
        _comment = comment;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
        writer.WriteComment(_comment); // append comment
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => true;
    public override bool CanRead => false;
}
```

and use it in your classes as:

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonCommentConverter), "Name of the person")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonCommentConverter), "Age of the person")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Serializing your class

```
 var person = new Person { Name = "Jack", Age = 22 };
 var personAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);
```

will create the following output:

```
{
    "Name": "Jack"/*Name of the person*/,
    "Age": 22/*Age of the person*/
}
```

Json.net will convert back this string into a `Person` class without a problem.

Comment: Why would you only solve it like this if you were desperate?

Answer (score 3):

As @RoToRa already said, JSON does not permit comments.

If you *still* want comments, and you want to output correct JSON, you could just make the comments part of the actual JSON data by changing the data layout. For example:

```
{
    "MyString": {
        "doc":   "My documentation string",
        "value": "Test"
    } 
}
```