# What is JSONC? Are JSONC and JSON-C different?

Tags: json, terminology

Recently came across the term `JSONC` in a YouTube API.  I browsed the Web, but found nothing much about it.  Can someone explain whether these two are the same or different?

Comment: if you dont know the answer, atleast dont downvote the people who are trying to find it.

Comment: `jsonc` can also refer to *json with comments* (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonc). For example used in [configuration files of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-with-comments).

Comment: jsonc is json with comments in the context of visual code at least!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

JSON-C seems to just be a variation of JSON mainly targeted at C development.  I.e., from the open source docs, "JSON-C **implements a reference counting object model** that allows you to easily construct JSON objects in C, output them as JSON formatted strings and parse JSON formatted strings back into the C representation of JSON objects."[ref^1](https://github.com/json-c/json-c/wiki)

From the YouTube API perspective (specifically, version 2, not the new version 3), The JSON-C response is just a condensed version of the JSON response (removing "duplicate, irrelevant or easily calculated values").[ref^2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc#Exclude_Elements)

Why would the JSON response have "duplicate, irrelevant or easily calculated values" values anyway?  Because it is converting the original ATOM XML format directly to JSON in a loseless conversion.  You can find out more details [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc#Comparing_JSON_and_JSONC).

However, I would suggest using [version 3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) of the YouTube Data API.  It is much easier to use.  =)

Answer (score 115):

There is also [`jsonc` aka "JSON with comments"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-with-comments), created by Microsoft and used by Visual Studio Code. The logic for it can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/node-jsonc-parser), alas without exhaustive specification (though I'd like to be proven wrong on this).

On top of that there is [this project with an actual specification which is also called `jsonc`, but also does far more than just adding comments](https://github.com/komkom/jsonc).

While there definitely is a use for these technologies, some critical thinking is advised. JSON containing comments is not JSON.

Comment: vscode uses this package for jsonc handling - https://github.com/Microsoft/node-jsonc-parser - as included here - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/extensions/json-language-features/server/package.json

Comment: “ JSON containing comments is not JSON”.  there  are different JSON extensions that support comments, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json/7901053#7901053

Comment: I've always had a problem with no comments in JSON.  So much I want to explain to future programmers.  Meanwhile, JSON where you can cut out some of the unneeded quotes is really appealing; I like the komkom version.  the MS version seems unnecessarily complicated, but usable.  Tragic that there's so many other things named JSONC.  I wish people would google for names before they use them and risk sabotaging their own projects.

Answer (score 7):

JSONC is an open-source, Javascript API created by Tomás Corral Casas for reducing the size of the amount of JSON data that is transported between clients and servers.  It uses two different approaches to achieve this, `JSONC.compress` and `JSONC.pack`.  More information can be found on the JSONC Github page:

https://github.com/tcorral/JSONC

Comment: Is that API the same thing as the mentioned JSON with comments? Or are those completely different and just happened to have the same abbreviation? I suspect, they are different

Comment: Different.  Follow the URLs to see.