# how can I resolve @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any on catch statement?

Tags: typescript, eslint

eg. I'm using `any` then, I got error: `Unexpected any. Specify a different type.`; Okay, let me use `unknown`, then I have error on e.message

```
try {
  // await code here
} catch (e: unknown) {
  throw(e.message) // e is type of unknown
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error object inside catch is of type unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68240884/error-object-inside-catch-is-of-type-unknown)

Comment: There is no guarantee that a thrown value is an instance of Error. You (or someone else who's function you call) could write `throw undefined;` and then when you try to read `e.message` in a `catch` block boom! runtime error. You'll need to do something like `if (e && e instanceof Error) { ... }` also note that `throw` is not a function and you shouldn't be throwing strings.