# How can I set the character "&" as a trigger for a sublime completions list?

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to make a `.sublime-completions` file where all the commands start with "&". The general format for this is:

```
        {
            "trigger": "&Command",
            "annotation": "basic function",
            "contents": "&Command",
            "kind": "function",
            "details": "Command description"
        },
```

The problem is that the trigger isn't picking up the **&** symbol so it'll only show after typing the first letter of the command (in this example, it's "C") and outputs an extra **"&"** symbol.

How can I get the **"&"** to be included with the trigger? I tried putting **\** infront of the **&** symbol but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your preferences (Win/Lin - **`Preferences → Settings`**, Mac - **`Sublime Text → Preferences → Settings`**) and add the following:

```json
"auto_complete_triggers":
    [
        {
            "characters": "&",
            "selector": "source",
        }
    ]
```

You can add additional [scopes](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/scope_naming.html) to `"selector"` to make it more specific. For example, if you only want this behavior in Javascript, you could change that line to `"selector": "source.js"`. If you want it in JS and HTML, the value would become `"source.js, text.html"`. To find the full scope at any point in a document, place your cursor and select **`Tools → Developer → Show Scope Name`**. The first line describes the document as a whole, and is generally all you need for this rule. However, feel free to make the rule as specific as you want.

You may also want to remove `&` from the list of word separation characters. This means that when you double-click on a word starting with `&`, that character is selected along with the rest of the word.

```json
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

The settings file needs to be valid [JSONC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851903/what-is-jsonc-are-jsonc-and-json-c-different), meaning that comments are allowed, and each setting needs to be separated by a comma `,`.