# Which Java/JSON library supports converting a JSON file that contains comments to a Java class?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

My JSON file's content is :

```
{
"MJ" : "Michael Jordan",
"KB" : "Kobe Bryant",
"KG" : "Kevin Garnet"
}
```

Now it is easy to convert this file (or string) to a Java class (e.g: `java.util.HashMap`) if I use Gson or Jackson or JsonSimple or another Java/JSON third-party library. E.g., I can use Gson like this:

```
//this returns the string above
String jsonString = TestReader.getStrFromJSonFile();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {}.getType();
HashMap<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

But,if my JSON file contains comments, most of the third-party libraries will not work.
e.g.:

> ```
>   {   
>        //Bulls   
>        "MJ" : "Michael Jordan",   
>        /*Lakers*/  
>        "KB" : "Kobe Bryant",    
>        //Boston Celtics    
>        "KG" : "Kevin Garnet"    
>    }
> ```

Now I'm even confused after googling and stackoverflowing a lot.  I have two questions:

1. Can a JSON file really contain any comments? I think it can because I see a lot of this in JSON files everyday. But >>> ([links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-i-comment-a-json-file))
2. If it can, how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Jackson supports comments if you enable that feature on the parser you use: http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonParser.Feature.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I comment a JSON file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-i-comment-a-json-file)

Comment: @WChargin In fact,that's just one of my question,and my key point is the second question.

Comment: Comments like that do not comprise [legal JSON](http://www.json.org/), so you must use a JSON parser that is specifically enabled to handle them.  No web service or other "generalized" source of JSON should produce comments that way.  (Basically what you really have is JavaScript, not JSON.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson supports comments if you enable that feature on the parser you use:

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.Feature.html

Comment: The link is dead.