# Are comments allowed in a javascript variable declared in JSON like notation?

Tags: javascript, json

Comments aren't allowed in *JSON* files (as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183018/3870761)). So, my question is if comments are allowed in *javascript* object declaration (in *JSON* like notation).

Example:

```
var myObject = {
    prop1: 'value1', // prop1 description
    prop2: 'value2' /* prop2 description */
}
```

Is this guaranteed to work or its browser dependent?

Comment: This is just javascript, of course comments are allowed.

Comment: Although this not json this object declaration with comments is allowed. `JSON.stringify(myObject)` will create valid json without problems.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to work because of the trailing comma, but that has nothing to do with the comments.

Comment: Thanks @Juhana yep, what a mistake, trailing comma won't work in IE, edited.

Comment: Tanks @dfsq, as you have made the first comment arguing its only javascript, provide it if you want as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: There is no such thing as JavaScript which is in JSON-like notation. It is JSON that is JavaScript-like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just normal usage of comments in javascript program, nothing special about it. You can use single or multi-line comments the way you usually would use:

```
var myObject = {
    prop1: 'value1', // prop1 description
    prop2: 'value2', /* prop2 description */
    prop3: /* or even so */ 'value3'
}
```

Also you should not confuse javascript object notation with JSON. Above is not JSON (and as you correctly stated comments are not allowed within JSON body), JSON is just a *string* representation of the javascript object.