# How do you add a comment to a json IAM policy?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

IAM policy are complicated beasts.  It would be nice to add a comment when crafting them.  For example,

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1422979261000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "route53:ListHostedZones",
      ],
      "Comment": "Foo"
      # or Bar
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Neither of these work.  Does there exist a way to add comments to these policies?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No.  In general, comments as you describe them [are not allowed in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-i-comment-a-json-file). To effectively create a comment, you would need to allow for a new element that describes comments.  Since AWS is the master of this json object, they would be responsible for allowing this.

They currently [only allow the following elements](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html):

- Version
- Id
- Statement
- Sid
- Effect
- Principal
- NotPrincipal
- Action
- NotAction
- Resource
- NotResource
- Condition

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I was aware that json in general doesn't support comments, but it's nice to know that even ad-hoc fields are not allowed.

Answer (score 50):

Hyper Anthony's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28303936/45773) is correct in the strict sense of 'comment' - however, in most situations you can at least use the `Sid` for pseudo comments to communicate the intent or any constraints etc.:

> The Sid (statement ID) is an optional identifier **that you provide** for the policy statement. You can assign a Sid value to each statement in a statement array. In services that let you specify an ID element, such as SQS and SNS, the Sid value is just a sub-ID of the policy document's ID. In IAM, the Sid value must be unique within a policy. *[emphasis mine]*

This is e.g. exemplified by the use of `TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions` within the (very helpful) AWS blog post [Demystifying EC2 Resource-Level Permissions](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2KPWZJJ4S26H6/Demystifying-EC2-Resource-Level-Permissions):

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- As mentioned in [Sid](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Sid) some services *might require this element and have uniqueness requirements for it*, but I haven't experienced resulting naming constraints yet.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I wanted to add a comment of the nature "I tried this thing that seems like it should obviously work, but it doesn't.  I don't have time to figure out why, so I'm using *".  Using Sid for high level docs is a good idea though.  Thanks.

Comment: Came here when looking to find out if this is possible.  Anyone that tries this and runs into problems, please comment here.

Comment: I also came here looking to find out how to comment a IAM policy.  How am I supposed to remember in 6 months who the AWS Principal code refers to? How is my team supposed to know?  It would really help if AWS supported a "display name" and "description" field for these policy statements.

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't support comment. but we can add 'Sid:' as a comment to categorize multiple service policies inside one single policy. below i am uploading single json policy for Ec2, S3, Lambda, ElasticBeanStalk services.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EC2FullAccess",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "autoscaling:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                        "autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
                        "ec2scheduled.amazonaws.com",
                        "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com",
                        "spot.amazonaws.com",
                        "spotfleet.amazonaws.com",
                        "transitgateway.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3FullAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "LambdaFullAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:ListStackResources",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "lambda:*",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "states:DescribeStateMachine",
                "states:ListStateMachines",
                "tag:GetResources",
                "xray:GetTraceSummaries",
                "xray:BatchGetTraces"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "acm:Describe*",
                "acm:List*",
                "autoscaling:Describe*",
                "cloudformation:Describe*",
                "cloudformation:Estimate*",
                "cloudformation:Get*",
                "cloudformation:List*",
                "cloudformation:Validate*",
                "cloudtrail:LookupEvents",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "codecommit:Get*",
                "codecommit:UploadArchive",
                "ec2:AllocateAddress",
                "ec2:AssociateAddress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroup*",
                "ec2:CreateLaunchTemplate*",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteLaunchTemplate*",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:Describe*",
                "ec2:DisassociateAddress",
                "ec2:ReleaseAddress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroup*",
                "ecs:CreateCluster",
                "ecs:DeRegisterTaskDefinition",
                "ecs:Describe*",
                "ecs:List*",
                "ecs:RegisterTaskDefinition",
                "elasticbeanstalk:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates",
                "logs:Describe*",
                "rds:Describe*",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "sqs:ListQueues"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "autoscaling:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:autoscaling:*:*:launchConfiguration:*:launchConfigurationName/awseb-e-*",
                "arn:aws:autoscaling:*:*:launchConfiguration:*:launchConfigurationName/eb-*",
                "arn:aws:autoscaling:*:*:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-*",
                "arn:aws:autoscaling:*:*:autoScalingGroup:*:autoScalingGroupName/eb-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CancelUpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:ContinueUpdateRollback",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplate",
                "cloudformation:ListStackResources",
                "cloudformation:SignalResource",
                "cloudformation:TagResource",
                "cloudformation:UntagResource",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/awseb-*",
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/eb-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudwatch:*:*:alarm:awseb-*",
                "arn:aws:cloudwatch:*:*:alarm:eb-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds",
                "codebuild:CreateProject",
                "codebuild:DeleteProject",
                "codebuild:StartBuild"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codebuild:*:*:project/Elastic-Beanstalk-*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:DeleteTable",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:TagResource"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/awseb-e-*",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/eb-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RebootInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-id": [
                        "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/awseb-e-*",
                        "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/eb-*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "ec2:LaunchTemplate": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:launch-template/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecs:DeleteCluster"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ecs:*:*:cluster/awseb-*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:*Rule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*Tags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetRulePriorities",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSecurityGroups"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/app/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/app/*/*/*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/awseb-*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/eb-*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/awseb-*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/eb-*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/*/awseb-*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/*/eb-*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/awseb-*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/eb-*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/*/awseb-*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/*/eb-*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/app/awseb-*/*/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/app/eb-*/*/*/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
                "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                "iam:CreateRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk*",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:instance-profile/aws-elasticbeanstalk*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:PolicyArn": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalk*",
                        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSElasticBeanstalk*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com",
                        "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                        "ec2.amazonaws.com.cn",
                        "autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
                        "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com",
                        "ecs.amazonaws.com",
                        "cloudformation.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling*",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForElasticBeanstalk*",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForElasticLoadBalancing*",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/managedupdates.elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForElasticBeanstalk*",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/maintenance.elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForElasticBeanstalk*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                        "autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
                        "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com",
                        "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com",
                        "managedupdates.elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com",
                        "maintenance.elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:DeleteLogGroup",
                "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:*DBSubnetGroup",
                "rds:AuthorizeDBSecurityGroupIngress",
                "rds:CreateDBInstance",
                "rds:CreateDBSecurityGroup",
                "rds:DeleteDBInstance",
                "rds:DeleteDBSecurityGroup",
                "rds:ModifyDBInstance",
                "rds:RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:db:*",
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:secgrp:awseb-e-*",
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:secgrp:eb-*",
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:snapshot:*",
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:subgrp:awseb-e-*",
                "arn:aws:rds:*:*:subgrp:eb-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Delete*",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::elasticbeanstalk-*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:CreateTopic",
                "sns:DeleteTopic",
                "sns:GetTopicAttributes",
                "sns:Publish",
                "sns:SetTopicAttributes",
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "sns:Unsubscribe"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*:*:ElasticBeanstalkNotifications-*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:*QueueAttributes",
                "sqs:CreateQueue",
                "sqs:DeleteQueue",
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:TagQueue"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:awseb-e-*",
                "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:eb-*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While Sid is a great solution to the lack of commenting ability, using Tags is also another approach not yet mentioned. Also, another approach is to stop using JSON altogether. Details below...

**Use Tags**

When a policy is created in AWS, [you can add tags to that policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_tags_customer-managed-policies.html) and that would allow you to insert user-generated comments in key value pairs.

**Stop using JSON**

Ideally your policy statements should not be stored in AWS because you do not get source code tracking there. A tool such as Github or CodeCommit should always be used to store your code prior to it being deployed to AWS. AWS should not be your source of truth for applications, but instead a place where your policies are deployed using [Cloudformation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/), [CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/), Terraform, [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), etc. In each of these cases your policy documents can be stored as YAML (or some other language) instead of JSON. For example, if you use Typescript + CDK, you can put comments in your code. Or if you're using Cloudformation, use YAML which supports comments. If you're using AWS CLI, use a YAML converter tool before consuming your json. I believe this is the most ideal answer to the original question as cloud environments such as AWS are almost never designed to easily track changes to deployed code over time. For example, an AWS IAM Policy [can only have 5 versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-versioning.html) before you have to delete one to insert a new version of the Policy.