# How to read JSON file with comments?

Tags: python, json

The comment are causing errors. I have a `contents.json` file which looks like:

```
{
"Fridge": [
    ["apples"],
    ["chips","cake","10"]    // This comment here is causing error
],
"car": [
    ["engine","tires","fuel"],
    ]
}
```

My python script is like this

```
import json
jsonfile = open('contents.json','r')
jsondata = jsonfile.read()
    
objec = json.loads(jsondata)

list_o = objec['Fridge']

for i in (list_o):
    print(i)
```

In my `list_o`, i am trying to load `Fridge` from `contents.json`file, when JSON file has that comment, it gives me an error, when the JSON file doesn't have the comment, the script runs properly.

I understand that comments is not proper JSON format, but is there any way to ignore comments of JSON file?

Comment: add a key like `"comments": "some text"

Comment: i am in a situation where i cannot modify the json file but i can totally modify my python script.

Comment: No, you can't ignore syntax errors.

Comment: You aren't being provided with JSON files; file a bug report with whoever is adding the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse json file with c-style comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29959191/how-to-parse-json-file-with-c-style-comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file per line and remove the comment part.

```
import json

jsondata = ""
with open('contents.json', 'r') as jsonfile:
    for line in jsonfile:
        jsondata += line.split("//")[0]

objec = json.loads(jsondata)

list_o = objec['Fridge']

for i in (list_o):
    print(i)
```

```
['apples']
['chips', 'cake', '10']
```

**Update**

You can also easily just use a library such as [commentjson](https://pypi.org/project/commentjson/). Just replace :

```
objec = json.loads(jsondata)
```

To

```
import commentjson  # python3 -m pip install commentjson
objec = commentjson.loads(jsondata)
```

Comment: While this may work most of the time, it's possible for it to fail depending on what's in the file.

Comment: @martineau, so far this works in this case, i was curious, in what case would this not work ?

Comment: It wouldn't work if you are using other comment styles such as `#` or if the real data in your json file contains a `//` character such as `["appl//es"],`. I updated the answer to use a library. It's more usable for your use case.

Comment: A fairly obvious example would be if a string in the JSON data contained a `//`. like `["engine","tires","fuel",'//oil']` — which is why I also said it was unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: Could be problematic if the JSON data is in a single line (not pretty printed)

Comment: If it's in a single line, then it should be safe to assume that there will be no comments in the middle as that would totally invalidate the json e.g. `{"abc": "def" // Some comment here "ghi": "jkl"}`. So if someone just added that `// Some comment here` in the middle, I guess someone has to be fired :)

Comment: @Thyag: Those kind of comments, aka single-line or in-line style comments, start with `//` and continue until the end of the line, so it's very unlikely they would be in JSON data put all on a single line for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Niel: Using a module like commentjson would probably be the best approach because ultimately what's needed is something that will actually *parse* the data in the file in order to separate them out — assuming that is syntactically possible.

Comment: @martineau yes agree. And as you pointed out already, my first solution is flawed and could fail depending on the contents of the json file.

Comment: Imagine that you're building a site like, say, StackOverflow, where you might want to return JSON responses that include code snippets.  And oh, hey, one of those code snippets is C-style code that includes an embedded `//` comment...

Answer (score 5):

@NielGodfreyPonciano's answer would work most of the time but would fail when `//` is part of a string.

For a more robust solution you can parse it as [JSON5](https://json5.org/), a superset of JSON that supports comments, with the [pyjson5](https://github.com/dpranke/pyjson5) module:

```
import json5

data = '''{
"Fridge": [
    ["apples"],
    ["chips","cake","10"]    // This comment here is causing error
],
"car": [
    ["engine","tires","fuel"],
    ]
}'''

print(json5.loads(data))
```

This outputs:

```
{'Fridge': [['apples'], ['chips', 'cake', '10']], 'car': [['engine', 'tires', 'fuel']]}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/MicroHatefulEnterprise

Answer (score 1):

Following @blhsing's and @NielGodfreyPonciano's answers, you could also achieve that with only built-in modules by using `regular expressions`:

```
import re
import json


with open("contents.json", "r") as JSONfile:
    objec = json.loads("".join(re.split(r"(?://|#).*(?=\n)", JSONfile.read())).strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following works for reading JSONC in Python, with using **re**:

```
    def parseJsonc(text):
        text_without_comment = re.sub(r'\/\*(\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\/|\/\/.*', '', text)
        return json.loads(text_without_comment)
```

View [here](https://regex101.com/r/XESfCa/1).

Comment: Could the regex be simplified with `\/\*(.|\s)*?\*\/|\/\/.*`? Or using the flag `re.DOTALL` even with `\/\*.*?\*\/|\/\/.*?$`

Comment: This also matches `//` and `/*` inside strings though.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73681312/9058671) I modified the regex to ignore comment tokens inside strings.
([Show on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gcQtkE/4))

```py
# This regex requires the X flag, to ignore whitespaces inside the regex
regex = r"""
        (
            "(?:\\"|[^"])*?" (?# First try to match balanced quotes)
        )
        | (?# If not successfull, try the following)
        (
            \/\*(?:.|\s)*?\*\/ (?# Match a block comment)
            |
            \/\/.* (?# Match a line comment)
        )
        """
```

Combining this with a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72168909/9058671) we can write a custom `JSONDecoder`

```py
import json
import re


class JSONWithCommentsDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self, **kwgs):
        super().__init__(**kwgs)

    def decode(self, s: str):
        regex = r"""("(?:\\"|[^"])*?")|(\/\*(?:.|\s)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)"""
        s = re.sub(regex, r"\1", s)  # , flags = re.X | re.M)
        return super().decode(s)
```

Now we can use it with

```py
with open("coontents.json") as f:
    js = json.loads(f.read(), cls = JSONWithCommentsDecoder)
```

Answer (score -4):

*"Errors due to comments"* is precisely what should happen because JSON documents should NOT contain comments. You will have to fix the data at the source before consuming. In other words, if your data contains javascript-style comments, then it is not a JSON anymore (just a random non-standard text file)

At the consuming side, any attempts to remove comments could be unsafe as JSON documents do not need to have newlines/pretty printed.

Comment: I don't think your "answer" is adding much to the discussion that either the OP already knows or someone else has already pointed out in a comment (or isn't obvious).