# What is the meaning of # Optional in Google API documentation

Tags: json, syntax, google-calendar-api, option-type

I am just beginning a study of the Google Calendar API. Here is a snippet which appears to be nested JSON syntax but I'd like to know more about the meaning of **# Optional** below (i.e. haven't found any discussion of this syntax in searching for JSON syntax):

```
"start": {
   "dateTime": "startTime",
   # Optional
   "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
},
"end": {
   "dateTime": "endTime",
   # Optional
   "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
},
```

Here is another snippet of this documentation where # is used differently:

```
"recurrence": [
   "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20110701T160000Z",
   # EXRULE, RDATE, EXDATE...
],
```

I am beginning to think this is just a comment in the documentation only - that is, it would not be considered *comments* in an actual JSON file per this:

[Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-i-comment-a-json-file)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just meant as a comment ... but it's not actual JSON syntax.