# unexpected char. error when uploading Chrome extension

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Chrome extension which works perfectly fine when I load it as an unpacked extension in Chrome. However, when I attempt to upload the zip to the Chrome Web Store, I receive the following manifest.json error:

**An error occurred: Failed to process your item.
manifest.json:8:4: unexpected char.**

I have already removed all comments from the JSON file. I even tested my JSON at http://jsonlint.com and it came back valid. Does anyone have any clue as to what the issue could be?

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "description": "Description goes here",
  "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["https://example.com"],
          "css": ["css/style.css"],
          "js": [
              "lib/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
              "scripts/main.js"
          ],
          "run_at": "document_idle"
      }
  ],
  "icons": {
      "16": "icons/16.png",
      "48": "icons/48.png",
      "128": "icons/128.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: `8:4` is line 8, character 4.  I think that puts it into the whitespace before `matches`.  Do you have something that looks like a space but isn't?  Or smart quotes?

Comment: Or resave the file in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Teepeemm - Your suggestion seems to have worked. Replacing that white space and re-uploading did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

In case someone else comes across this question with a different problem (that I just had), it's because I had stray comments left in my manifest [which of course I pulled from the example one](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest), which aren't allowed in [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244858/452383)

Comment: I can't believe they put an example that doesn't work! Even the values they used are dumb and don't represent the format of the variable!

Comment: Weird, it works when unpackaged, but when you try to publish it Google complains..

Answer (score 0):

You cant have any comments in manifest.json file when publising.