# How to tokenize this string

Tags: visual-c++

This is the output from an HTTP request:

```
{"players":[{"SteamId":"76561197184882325","CommunityBanned":false,"VACBanned":true,"NumberOfVACBans":1,"DaysSinceLastBan":1010,"NumberOfGameBans":1,"EconomyBan":"none"}]}
```

How do I get things from it in C++ like:

```
uint64 SteamId = 76561197184882325;
bool CommunityBanned = false;
bool VACBanned = true;
int NumberOfVACBans = 1;
```

and so on

Comment: You need a JSON parser; you could start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/json/

Comment: You didnt help me very much

Comment: Sorry you fill that way... There is no JSON parser in the `std::`, so you have to either write it yourself or look for third-party implementation. Please see this for other options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471581/c-c-json-parser