# Send JSON data from C++ to Python

Tags: c++, json, api, websocket, network-programming

Is there a way to send data by encoding the data in JSON format using C++? I need to stream video frames and some information about each frame over the network! I tried using sockets but I was unable to synchronize frames and their corresponding information!

Comment: There's a few [JSON libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471581/c-c-json-parser/36471724) for C++. If the problem is more with the socket behavior than the contents of what's being sent over them, some socket stuff might be necessary. As written, this is a somewhat unanswerably broad question because we don't really know exactly what problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Seeing that you said "you tried" so you should be able to post a [example] to describe the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

You can use socket and add unique frame number to your json, for example frame send

```
{
   "data":"ADFF..",
   //....
   "frame_id":"1234"
   }
```

And response should be like that

```
{
"frame_id":"1234",
"result":"ok"
}
```