# Parse string and replace

Tags: c++

How i could convert this javascript code to c++

```js
key = {"|1|":"A","|2|":"B","|4|":"C","|3|":"D"}

y = "|1||2||3||4|"

for (i in key) 
  y = y.replace(i,key[i])

console.log(y)
```

output: `ABDC`

I got the "decoding key" in a `std::string` like:

```cpp
  std::string key = "{\"|1|\":\"A\",\"|2|\":\"B\",\"|3|\":\"D\",\"|4|\":\"C\"}";
```

Based on the properties of this key do a string replace in `my_string`.

Example:

```
std::string key = "{\"|1|\":\"A\",\"|2|\":\"B\",\"|3|\":\"D\",\"|4|\":\"C\"}";

std::string my_string = "|1||2||3||4|";
// . . .
```

Replace in `my_string` `|1|` to `A`, `|2|` to `B`, `|3|` to `D`, `|4|` to `C`

`|1|` to `A`, `|2|` to `B` ... etc comes from the `std::string key`

Then `my_string` now is `ABDC`.

Do i need to convert the `std:: string key` to another data type? I mean something similar to an object like on javascript, im not familiar with c++.

Comment: don't know javascript but you could try a map

Comment: @Renan What do you need to do? To convert the string "1234" to the string "ABDC"?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i updated the post with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalents of java dictionnary is map or unordered_map

As for your json question, you need a library to parse json, I recommend the [excellent one from Professor Lemire (github lemire)](https://github.com/lemire/simdjson_cxxopts_tools)

I just wrote you a simple json parser for you. Note that you will need to compile with c++1z or you will get the warning: `decomposition declaration only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1z`

`g++ -std=c++1z test.cpp && ./a.out`

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void jsonDecode(unordered_map <string, char> &m, string s) {
    constexpr char delimiter = '"';
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ) {
       if (s[i++] == delimiter) {
          stringstream ss;
          while (s[i] != delimiter)
            ss << s[i++];
          string key = ss.str();
          ++i;
          while (s[i] != delimiter) i++;
          char value = s[++i];
          m[key] = value;
          i+=2;
       }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    unordered_map <string, char> m;
    string s = R"({"|1|":"A","|2|":"B","|3|":"D","|4|":"C"})";
    jsonDecode(m, s);
    string y = "|1||2||3||4|";

    for (auto &[k,v] : m)
            y.replace(y.find(k), k.size(), string(1, v));

    cout << y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
ABDC
```

You can read about [replace method here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

Comment: I cant define the key like you did, i get it in a response from a post request, and it comes in this format: `{\"|1|\":\"A\",\"|2|\":\"B\",\"|3|\":\"D\",\"|4|\":\"C\"}`

Comment: you can decode the json and put it in a map with a json library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471581/c-c-json-parser/36471724

Comment: Is not possible to convert the string to a map?

Comment: I added a custom parser, easy to do, let me know. NB: this is assuming that you have always 3 char (so no 1x digit)

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL it also can have 4 char it goes from `|1|` to  `|36|`

Comment: i did not understand how to define the `s`

Comment: see my edit, it works on my laptop, sorry was outside before, coding on a mobile phone is not easy!

Comment: on the image above, look at the output of y, its not `ABDC` , i think its because not using the `R` like you did, how i could convert the `std::string s` in `encode` to the same you did using `R(`

Comment: but like i told you before, the string cames from another variable its not defined somewhere in the code

Comment: could you print s? `cout << s << endl;` at the beginning of your function? I will be able to fix it quickly for you

Comment: ok see my edit, your string is parsed as " instead of \" as \ is an escape character

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct "translation" to C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<unordered_map>
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> dictionary = { {"|1|","A"} , {"|2|", "B"}, {"|4|", "C"}, {"|3|", "D"} };
    std::string y = "|1||2||3||4|";
    size_t pos;
    for (auto& a : dictionary) {
        while((pos = y.find(a.first)) != std::string::npos)
            y.replace(pos, a.first.length(), a.second);
    }
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```