# Regex_search c++

Tags: c++, regex

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {

    std::string s = "{\"|1|\":\"A\",\"|2|\":\"B\",\"|37|\":\"4234235\",\"|4|\":\"C\"}";

    std::regex regex("37\\|\\\\\":\\\\\"\\K\\d*");

    std::smatch m;

    regex_search(s, m, regex);
    std::cout << "match: " << m.str(1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does it not match the value `4234235`?

Testing the regex here:
https://regex101.com/r/A2cg2P/1
It does match.

Comment: Attempting to parse JSON-formatted data in C++ using regular expressions will only end in tears. To do this correctly [you should use a real JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471581/c-c-json-parser/36471724).

Comment: Just a side note: Representing regex patterns using [raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) is way easier,to write and better to read. But @Sam is correct, it's pretty hoeless to get that right. Use a JSON parser library like nlohmann's.

Comment: Much like trying to use regex to parse HTML:  https://blog.codinghorror.com/content/images/2014/Apr/stack-overflow-regex-zalgo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your online regex test is wrong because your actual text is `{"|1|":"A","|2|":"B","|37|":"4234235","|4|":"C"}`, you may see that your regex [does not match it](https://regex101.com/r/OvAxPt/1).

Besides, you are using an ECMAScript regex flavor in `std::regex`, but your regex is PCRE compliant. E.g. ECMAScript regex does not support `\K` match reset operator.

You need a `"\|37\|":"(\d+)` regex, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OvAxPt/2). *Details*:

- `"\|37\|":"` - literal `"|37|":"` text
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

See [the C++ demo](https://ideone.com/MtZoHM):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string s = "{\"|1|\":\"A\",\"|2|\":\"B\",\"|37|\":\"4234235\",\"|4|\":\"C\"}";
    std::cout << s <<"\n";
    std::regex regex(R"(\|37\|":"(\d+))");
    std::smatch m;
    regex_search(s, m, regex);
    std::cout << "match: " << m.str(1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```