# Eclipse Neon Json editor - allow comments

Tags: json, eclipse, comments, eclipse-neon

Is it possible to allow comments in JSON file?

I have a JSON file with comment lines marked with `//` on the beginning. The file is properly read by `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`, but JSON editor marks it as error (*Expected value at `row:column`*) and whole project is marked with error.
Is it possible to allow comments or disable validation for one file only?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the JSON format is very simple, Eclipse's built-in JSON validation doesn't provide any granular control over what is marked as an error.

I see two options:

1. Use pseudo-comments [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244858/2945358).
2. Disable JSON validation for that specific file.

   - Window > Preferences > Validation
   - In the 'Validator' list, find "JSON Validator" and click the '...' in the Settings column
   - Add an exclude group, then add a rule for the specific file you want the validator to ignore

As an aside, the JSON format doesn't support any kind of comment notation.  Strictly speaking, that error message is correct - but in this case the parser you're using (Jackson) is configured to allow something out-of-spec.