# I get a "Expected name at XX:YY" error on .json files in Eclipse. What is wrong?

Tags: json, eclipse, object, jsondoc

I have this code in it now...with the entra line after the closing }...

[Here is a larger screenshot of it now!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbbA2.png)

```
{
  "menu" : {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File",
    "popup": {
      "menuitem": [
        { "value" : "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()" },
        { "value" : "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()" },
        { "value" : "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. It seems you missed one '}' at the end of the JSON.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't closed the `}` at the end of the json. The correct json would be as follows.

```
{
  "menu" : {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File",
    "popup": {
      "menuitem": [
        { "value" : "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()" },
        { "value" : "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()" },
        { "value" : "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error reading with that correct code :|

Comment: I'll try uninstalling the json editor and reinstalling i guess?

Comment: I did, even though it validates in there it won't in my Eclipse!

Comment: That's really strange. Can you provide another screenshot with the updated json ? Also can you try to leave a new line after the last `}` character ?

Comment: Just amended the question with an updated screenshot of all the screen and the code! Hope this shows it better!

Answer (score 2):

It happened the same thing on my Eclipse Photon, and looking at some of the examples here and assistance, I tried to edit the file and save it. Errors still the same.

I did a simple trick which actually does suffice.

Using the auto format from Eclipse, Ctrl + Shift + F, then save and then undo (Ctrl + Z), the error miraculously disappeared.

Still ain't sure why the scenario is like this though.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file in the eclipse, the error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error in STS 3.9.4 which is built on top of Eclipse Oxygen. This is thrown by the Json Validator used by Eclipse editor implementation due to the presence of the embedded comments within the Json file. Though, at runtime, this is ignored by the Jackson marshaller implementation used by the Spring Boot. Only that, Eclipse's JSON validator seems to be strict about the comments.

So, I configured the editor preferences to exclude the file from doing JSON validation as suggested at here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41704569/5107365.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And thanks to the tips of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to see the formatting of brackets **("{" and "[").** I realized there are "extra" single side brackets (like open without closing) in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> mode. But when I undo it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the extra brackets were gone. It seems like some escape-sequence control codes are in the file. And it being removed when using the above trick.

It is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by `danielctw` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54107067/8147680) worked for me for the first time but not again. I believe the error might be due to hidden characters.

I solved this by copying the contents of the json file and pasting it into notepad(in windows) and then copying it from there and pasting it into the json file and the errors were gone.

I somewhere read about how some hidden characters are removed in a notepad file but I am not sure and if someone knows, please mention so that me and others can learn.