# npm start error but node index.js works

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I started learning nodejs and followed this tutorial to create a simple web app.

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-tutorial-getting-started-with-node-js/

According to the tutorial I can run the web app using either 'npm start' or node index.js' . When I use node install.js it works and give the result. But when I use npm start this error occurs.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file /var/www/html/nodejs/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '/' at 1:1
npm ERR! // package.json
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: /var/www/html/nodejs/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file.    JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/html/nodejs/npm-debug.log
```

As I'm a total beginner to nodejs and npm I can't figure out what went wrong.
Does anyone know how to fix this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` file? There's an error in there somewhere.

Comment: `"package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript."` JSON does not support comments.

Comment: Thanks. It was my mistake as I've used // package.json as a comment in package.json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in your package.json. You can't use the comment `// package.json`. For more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244858/628699).

To describe the two situations you're encountering:

When you use `npm start`, you're using npm's CLI to look in the package.json for that project directory and run whatever command exists at the [start value](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values). If you wanted to run your app using `npm start`, you'd have a line in `package.json` like this:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
},
...
```

`package.json` is JSON so it needs to parse like valid JSON.

When you use `node index.js`, you're bypassing npm entirely and using node to fire up index.js. If there's a parsing error in `package.json`, it doesn't matter since that file isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do
*npm install --save-dev node*
and it will work ..