# How to place comments in Postman?

Tags: comments, postman

How to place comments inside Postman? Specifically in the JSON request body section?

I want to comment-out a particular key or value from the request body so that it is not sent.

Commenting out a JSON key/value pair with `//` or `/* ... */` appears as a styled comment inside Postman:

[image: comments appear to work]

But sending this request results in server errors such as the below, and it's clear that the commented-out line is being sent as part of the request body:

> Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)
> at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 2, column: 6
> ]

The JSON spec does not allow comments: [Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json)

I want Postman to strip the commented lines prior to being sent in the request.

Comment: Hi, you may have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json)

Comment: There is nothing magic about that body in Postman. It is just plain JSON. So unfortunately - as stated by the accepted answer to [Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244858) - the answer is ***No***. A possible workaround is to add a "phony" field to your JSON data, like `"_comment": "comment text goes here...",`. - Of course, the trick to *comment out* some of your JSON data would be to simply change the name of the key that you want to "disable".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can write documentation and comments [using the description section](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/using_markdown_for_descriptions) of the requests, collections or folders.

Comment: I just want to disable some code not want to add comments or descriptions..how can I do that?

Comment: same question as @MahenderReddyYasa

Comment: You can disable code using either a `// <single line of code>` or a `/** <multiple lines of code */` pattern like you would do for any code written in Javascript.

Comment: OP is asking how to stop Postman including commented code in requests, this is the problem.

Comment: @PratikMandrekar not sure why this answer is accepted by OP but even I'm looking for an answer where I can comment a line of code in my json body without removing the lines, I tried `//`, `/**/` but these returned me error saying `"JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): `

Comment: `maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10, column: 6]"`

Answer (score 23):

Finally, since Postman v8.3.0 you can do this in your collections `pre-request` script:

```
// Strip JSON Comments
if (pm?.request?.body?.options?.raw?.language === 'json') {
    const rawData = pm.request.body.toString();
    const strippedData = rawData.replace(
        /\\"|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|(\/\/.*|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)/g,
        (m, g) => g ? "" : m
    );
    pm.request.body.update(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(strippedData)));
}
```

This strips all comments from the json and sets the current body to the cleaned one, there are more examples for other body types (GraphQL, URL Encoded, Form Data) in the [original github post](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4808#issuecomment-826838064) this code is based from.

Comment: This works great! But I needed to additionally update header: `pm.request.upsertHeader({key: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/json'});`.

It seems like updating body resets content type to plain text.

Answer (score 12):

A "Comments" option/button is above the send button for every request.

But still, we can't add a comment in the request body, maybe in future, they'll provide this feature.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

It has been done by `Script` 
https://community.postman.com/t/request-body-should-be-able-to-be-commented/8288

**Pre-request Script** create an object, convert it to a string, then expose it

```js
object = {
   // product: "{{displayName}}",
   price : "15.5"
}
pm.environment.set("object", JSON.stringify(object));
```

**Request Body** called the variable `object`

```
{{object}}
```

Comment: See it in action on YoouTube: [Add comments to JSON body in Postman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bX4-cLPcD2Q)

Comment: That's the only solution that worked for me on the latest Postman for macOS (v9.24.0; Desktop Platform v9.22.2)

Answer (score 4):

I checked with GitHub where Postman has their feature requests and bugs tracked, Link here:

> Feature request: Raw body editor JSON comment #3358
> https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3358

You can go and add comments there so that this feature would be considered for their next release. Also, I found out that you can copy and paste `<!-- comment-->` to make a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Postman v9.13.0 you can do so using block comments

[image]

Comment: Multi-line comment doesn't work in postman. I tried the same you showed above but it didn't work and sent /* *? block in the native request.

Answer (score 0):

Not the actual question's answer, but this addresses the highly upvoted comment below the question:

> I just want to disable some code not want to add comments or descriptions..how can I do that? – Mahender Reddy Yasa

Ignoring the comment validation and sending request is now working for me in latest postman **7.7.3** 64 bit version of windows.

[image: Postman inputs]

Comment: There is a clear error shown on the side. Please verify that.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, Ignoring that validation and sending request will work. In above case `Description` will not send to server.

Comment: Worked here with "//"

Comment: No, it didn't work. Even if you use a single comment it sends commented line in the native request.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, you can add comments after your request object.

```
{
  "name":"Abc",
  "number":"278389239"
}

// Your Comment

/**

    Your Comments

**/
```

[image: You can get a more clear image from this screenshot]