# comment out lines in simple json to put some description

Tags: json

How do I add comments in a simple JSON file which be read from s3 in AWS. This is my JSON file.

```
{
    "Parameters": {
        "KeyPairName": "mykey",
        "InstanceTypes": "t2.micro",

        "prodImageIds": "ami-d7abd1b8",
        "testImageIds": "ami-e41b618b",
        "devImageIds": "ami-8f8afde0"
    },
    "StackPolicy": {
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "NotAction": "Update:Delete",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find answer from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json

Answer (score 10):

JSON specification doesn't include comments of any kind. You can simply add a standard key/value pair with a key that gets ignored by the application (maybe `_comment`) but there is no way to insert a proper comment.

Here the spec details: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 4):

I usually do something like adding 
`"------------------------------------------" : "------------------------------------------"` to visually separate "sections".