# Are comments allowed in a JSON file for boost read_json?

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

This is a homotopy of the json file I always used to read through `boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json`

And it was always working.

```
/**********************************************/
/*                 the title                  */
/**********************************************/



{
    "garden": {
        "side1": {
            "treeA1": "apple",
            "treeA2": "orange",
            "treeA3": "banana",
        },
        "side2": {
            "treeB1": "orange",
            "treeB2": "palm",
            "treeB3": "cherry",
        }
    },
    "house": ""
}
```

I upgraded my boost version from `1.58.0` to `1.65.0` and now I receive an exception because of the comments. When I remove the comments, everything is fine.

Am I making a mistake somewhere or is it a bug in the new version of boost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are not JSON.

The old parser did have them, but didn't properly support unicode.

Here's the message in [the release notes for Boost 1.59.0](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_59_0.html):

> Property Tree:
>
> - A new JSON parser with full Unicode support.
> - **Breaking
>   change:** The new parser does not support comments or string
>   concatenation in JSON files. These features were non-standard
>   extensions of the old parser but their removal could break code which
>   was relying on them.

Answer (score 0):

The [official JSON standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) does not define a syntax for comments ([here's the reason why](http://youtu.be/-C-JoyNuQJs?t=48m53s)).

Support for comments is implemented (or not) on a per-parser basis. It was probably something that Boost once supported for convenience but later removed for compliance (I'm speculating, as I don't use Boost myself).

If Boost no longer supports comments, you will have to strip them out before parsing. There are plenty of 3rd party implementations for that very purpose. See [Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/) for suggestions.