# How to use boost json lib to parse a json file with comments?

Tags: c++, json, boost

I'm new to boost library and I really need some help. In my case, I need to use boost lib to parse an external JSON file with comments(eg. "//" symbol). I use the following code to parse the unformatted json.

```
boost::property_tree::ptree root;
boost::property_tree::read_json<boost::property_tree::ptree>(file_path,root);
```

It fails since the json file is not a standard file. I also noticed the reference in [Are comments allowed in a JSON file for boost read_json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187201/are-comments-allowed-in-a-json-file-for-boost-read-json). However. I still use this unformatted file for my case.

My question is whether there is a 'ignore_comments' like nlohmann lib in boost lib or not. How I can handle this issue under the condition of boost lib.

Comment: Rather than having comments, have you considered a comment data field that's not used by your program?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option to allow non-standard behaviour for the boost.json.parser:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/json/doc/html/json/input_output.html#json.input_output.parsing.non_standard_json

```
parse_options opt;                                  // all extensions default to off
opt.allow_comments = true;                          // permit C and C++ style comments to appear in whitespace
//opt.allow_trailing_commas = true;                   // allow an additional trailing comma in object and array element lists
//opt.allow_invalid_utf8 = true;                      // skip utf-8 validation of keys and strings

value jv = parse( "[1,2,3,] // comment ", storage_ptr(), opt );
```

This should do what you want. You'll probably need to read your file as text first, though.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the usage of that storage_ptr (info here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/json/doc/html/json/allocators/storage_ptr.html). But you'll figure it out ! ;)

Comment: You can just default it as you did (or just `{}`) unless you want to control/reuse allocation

Comment: @nick Hi, thanks for your idea. Unfortunately, I'm using boost 1.62, JSON lib wasn't introduced in that version... So I have to write some c++ code to remove "//" or "/* */" manually before feeding it into read_json.  Maybe somebody could validate your mentioned solution.

Comment: @terry: Oooh, right. That's why have that property_tree stuff there. Sorry.
Time to update then ! (but you already knew that ;) )
The C++ comment formatting rules are not too complex, fortunatly.