# Is it possible to have comments in Log4J2 JSON configuration

Tags: json, log4j2

I have log4j2 configured using JSON format, e.g.:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "monitorInterval": 60,
    "properties": {
      ...
    },
    "appenders": {
      ...
    },

    "loggers": {
      "asyncRoot": {
        ...
```

etc.
The configuration is quite complex, so it requires some clarifications for whoever attempts to understand or change it in the future.

If this configuration was in XML, I could specify comments clarifying each section right in the configuration (changing my configuration to XML is not an option). But JSON doesn't have comments as a concept, and  recommendation is [to specify comments as data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json). E.g.:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "monitorInterval": 60,
    "_comment_": "here we go",
    "properties": {
```

But I'm not sure if something like that is a good idea in log4j2 case: instead of making configuration more clear, it actually adds a bulk to it, such comments are not clearly separated from actual data, and I am not sure if it will cause any stability / performance issues parsing configuration (as you can see, this configuration is parsed every 60 sec, so...)

Is there any common / recommended approach to describe the configuration with log4j2?
Or did you successfully test/use the above approach (comments as data)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have in-line comments in `log4j2 JSON` configuration file. You can write comment in below way -

```
{
"configuration": {           // this is comment
"monitorInterval": 60,       // set monitor interval here
"properties": {
  ...
},
"appenders": {
  ...
},

"loggers": {                // set logger details here
  "asyncRoot": {
    ...
```

It is because `log4j2` uses `Jackson` for parsing `JSON` configuration file and `Jackson` has option to enable comments in `JSON`.

Although, writing comments in this way may show you error in IDE like eclipse as `JSON` standard does not support comments.

Comment: perfect, it works. Lets hope future versions of log4j2 don't break this "accidental feature".

Answer (score 0):

Additional information: Log4J2 enables comments explicitly in [JsonConfiguration implementation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/json/JsonConfiguration.html):

> ```
> protected ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
>     return new ObjectMapper().configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);
> }
> ```

It refers to a property from `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`, which describes details on which comments are supported and why:

> ```
> /**
> * Feature that determines whether parser will allow use
> * of Java/C++ style comments (both '/'+'*' and
> * '//' varieties) within parsed content or not.
> *<p>
> * Since JSON specification does not mention comments as legal
> * construct,
> * this is a non-standard feature; however, in the wild
> * this is extensively used. As such, feature is
> * <b>disabled by default</b> for parsers and must be
> * explicitly enabled.
> */
> ALLOW_COMMENTS(false)
> ```

Feature is not documented anywhere in Log4J, also notice that by default Jackson has it disabled.