# Error in parsing JSON using codeable

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I am trying to pass some data from a JSON file using the new(ish) codeable capability in Swift. I have used the below syntax before without issue. I believe I may have something set up wrong, however, as I can't seem to understand why I keep receiving the below message when the JSON format has been approved by a JSON parser.

The error message:

> error:dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

The code in my QuestionFactory file...

```
class QuestionFactory {

func parseJSON(filename fileName: String) -> Quiz? {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") {
        print(url)
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            print("data received is \(data.count) bytes:\n\(data)")
            print(data)
            print(data as NSData)
            let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Quiz.self, from: data)

            print(jsonData)
        } catch {
            print("error:\(error)")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

The code in my initial ViewController:

```
class LaunchScreen: UIViewController {


  private var quiz: Quiz?
  private let jsonFileName = "QuizData"


 func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createQuiz()
 }


   private func createQuiz() {
    let questionFactory = QuestionFactory()
    guard let parsedQuiz = questionFactory.parseJSON(filename: jsonFileName) else {
        print("Error creating quiz")
        return
    }
    quiz = parsedQuiz
}

func movesToMainMenuScreen() {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 1.5
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade
    self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey:nil)
    let mainMenuVC: UIViewController = MainMenuViewController(quiz: quiz!) >> I am receiving an error here as well, perhaps due to my mainMenuVC's required init?
    navigationController?.pushViewController(mainMenuVC, animated: false)
}
```

In my mainMenuViewController:

```
class mainMenuViewController: UIViewController {

private var quiz: Quiz! {
    didSet {
    tableViewAdapter = AnswerTableViewAdapter(answers: quiz.questions[0].answers) >> Although, it is not obviously reaching this far to read through the JSON.
}

required init(quiz: Quiz) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    defer {
        self.quiz = quiz
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

The JSON looks like this...

```
{
"questions":[
             {
             "text": "1. Where will the 2022 World cup be held?",
             "answers": [
                         {
                         "text": "Qatar",
                         "isCorrect": true,
                         "answerType": "2"
                         },
                         {
                         "text": "دولة قطر",
                         "isCorrect": true,
                         "answerType": "1"
                         },
                         {
                         "text": "Jamaica",
                         "isCorrect": false,
                         "answerType": "0"
                         },
                         {
                         "image":"qatarFlag",
                         "isCorrect": true,
                         "answerType": "3"
                         }
                         ]
             }]
}
```

The Model files....

Quiz.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Quiz: Decodable {
  var questions: [Question]
}
```

Question.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Question: Decodable {
  var text: String
  var answers: [Answer]
}
```

Answer.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Answer: Decodable {
  var text: String
  var image: String
  var isCorrect: Bool
  var answerType: String
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see the JSON string you're decoding when you get the error and also the definition of `Quiz`

Comment: Apologies, I hit submit, before finishing my question.

Comment: Look at the (NS)data dump. It must start with `<7b`

Comment: I copy pasted your current JSON in a JSON validator, and it doesn't seem to be valid. You have extra `}]` at the end. Or it is a typo in your sample?

Comment: As the error suggests - The JSON you are using is invalid. Use https://jsonformatter.org to validate your JSON.

Comment: Apologies, I entered in an extra }] by mistake. I have now edited the original question to remove those extra brackets.

I printed out the NSData and this is the start of it...

data received is 10085 bytes:
10085 bytes
10085 bytes
<2f2a200a

Comment: " <2f2a200a": Your file start with `/* \n` then. You have a header/comment in your file, and there is no comment in JSON (cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183018/1801544). Remove it.

Comment: Argh, so annoying! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

There is extra

```
    ]
}
```

added on last two lines remove these both closing brackets and try to parse JSON.

And make your model's properties to optional to avoid nullable crashes.

The Model files....

Quiz.swift

```
import Foundation
struct Quiz: Decodable {
    var questions: [Question]?
}
```

Question.swift

```
import Foundation
struct Question: Decodable {
  var text: String?
  var answers: [Answer]?
}
```

Answer.swift

```
import Foundation
struct Answer: Decodable {
  var text: String?
  var image: String?
  var isCorrect: Bool?
  var answerType: String?
}
```

Comment: The extra ]} will not give the error in the question.

Comment: I tried on my system and it works fine after removing that extra brackets. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Read again, what error do you get *before* removing them?

Comment: Yes, apologies, I accidentally added those extra brackets. I have removed them so that the JSON now works in the parser. I actually made those endpoints optional before but it also didn't work.