# How to propose some revision to RFC(s) for JSON to account for comments?

Tags: json, parsing, comments, rfc, data-interchange

I found a few RFCs for JSON. What would be the best way to request a modification to the grammar or parser section(s) in order to propose the idea of supporting comments? As I understand it, JSON does not officially support comments. I understand there are rationales against using comments in JSON, but I'd still like to make a proposal for something that might work.

- See [Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json)
- See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)
- See [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)
- See [RFC 7159](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt)
- See [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure for independent submissions (that is, submissions which do not come from the IAB, IETF or IRTF) to the RFC Editor is described on the [Independent Submissions page](https://www.rfc-editor.org/about/independent/).

Anyone can submit any idea as an RFC, but you should carefully consider the reasons why comments are discouraged from inclusion in JSON, particularly the security-related reasons. (You'll need to do that review anyway as part of the submission process.)