# Can I comment on firebase.json file?

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, comments, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I need to comment out some lines from the `firebase.json` file:

Example:

```
"rewrites": [
      // {
      //  "source": "/blog/*", 
      //  "function": "handleBlog"
      // },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

In this case, I want to disable that `rewrite` temporarily but I do not want to delete the code.

The fact is that JSON files do not allow comments and I get an error from VSCode telling me that.

But if I set the Language Mode to `JSON with Comments`, the errors from VSCode are gone.

[image]

But is it safe to do? How does Firebase handle a `firebase.json` file with comments?

Comment: `json` with comments is no more `json`. It has `jsonc` file extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had commented JSON in my one of my `firebase.json`s for a while without issue.

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "headers": [
            /*{
              "source": "*.html",
              "headers": [
                {
                  "key": "Content-Security-Policy",
                  "value": "default-src 'self' ..."
                }
              ]
            },*/
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tested and so far is working for me too!

Answer (score 3):

`JSON` format does not support comments. Comments of the form //… or /*…*/ are not allowed in `JSON` [More info can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183018/9233618).

As far as `firebase` goes, I am not familiar with it, but if set Language Mode to `JSON with Comments` in VSCode, you will get `JSONC` file format, not `JSON`. `JSONC` is used specifically in [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-with-comments):

> In addition to the default JSON mode following the JSON specification, VS Code also has a JSON with Comments (jsonc) mode. This mode is used for the VS Code configuration files such as settings.json, tasks.json, or launch.json.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase's documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#direct_requests_to_container) use `//` for comments. I'd say it's safe to follow their approach.

I've also tested this format of commenting in `.firebaserc`. It works in there as well for me.