# Requiring a JSON with comments in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, json5

If you use typescript you can init a default tsconfig.json, and that json will have javascript // and /* */ comments in it. I've encountered a situation with ts-jest where I need to require my tsconfig and parse it, but jest is not parsing it because json doesn't allow comments. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json) I'm not sure how typescript handles it, but it seems to deviate from the rule.

```
// this fails if tsconfig has comments
const tsconfig = require('./tsconfig')
```

I want to keep the comments because they are really helpful to understand and maintain my tsconfig.json, and I want to require my config to be able to avoid duplicating code and make things more dynamic.

Is there a way to require a json file with comments using nodejs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[json5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5) can do the trick. Install JSON5 and then:

```
const JSON5 = require('json5');
const tsconfig = JSON5.parse(jsontxt);
```

Note that removing comments by yourself is possible but has several pitfalls, and that's why it's not recommended. You should look for:

- Strings may contain sequences that look like comments, only they are not.
- Comments may contain sequences that look like string beginning, only they are not.
- Strings may contain `"` that don't mark string end such as `"foo\"bar"`. It's more confusing with `"foo\\"`, where the second " does end the string.
- A `//` comment may contain `/*`, but that does not start a multi line comment.
- A `//` in a multi line comment does not start a single-line comment, such that removing comments in  `/* // */  "hi"` results with `"hi"`.
- Does a `\` continue a single-line to the next line? Does a `\*/` end a multi line comment, or does the `\` make the `*` act differently? (Neither are supported in JavaScript).
- are multi line strings supported (they are in JavaScript)? How are they declared/dealt with.

Answer (score 3):

[`require-json5`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-json5) is purpose-built for this:

```
const requireJSON5 = require('require-json5');
const tsconfig = requireJSON5('./tsconfig.json');
```

Or even more simply:

```
require('require-json5').replace();
var tsconfig = require("./tsconfig");
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by pre-processing the json to strip the comments. The following code is doing the job for me:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const stripForwardSlashForwardSlashComment = new RegExp('//(.*)', 'g')
const stripForwardSlashStarComment = new RegExp('[/][*](.*)[*][/]', 'gm')
let jsontxt = fs.readFileSync('./tsconfig.json', 'utf8')
jsontxt = jsontxt.replace(stripForwardSlashForwardSlashComment,'').replace(stripForwardSlashStarComment, '')
const tsconfig = JSON.parse(jsontxt)
```

Self answer note: Posting to keep this public and get some feedback

Comment: This is not safe. E.g. `["//text"]` where the string should be kept intact, although it contains something that looks like a comment.

Comment: Best answer for me! the RegExp's are incomplete but a good entry point to solve this for me. Think: the rule is: whitespace or not '(\b)?' followed by a / # or * as first character. drop the rest eg. (\b)?(#.*) for the hashtag. The basic rule. Then this works for most (but not all) cases (yet)!