# JSON Comments Possibility

Tags: json, vba, parsing

I am a complete beginner and trying to use JSON with VBA. This is to pass data from outside excel into the application so I can apply VBA.

The JSON file can look complicated and so to help I was wondering if comments can be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON does not support comments.

Anything that you put in the JSON object will be treated as data

Comment: *... will be treated as data*.  Or as an error if it doesn't conform to JSON syntax!

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly add comments, but you could just create new keys, where you put in your comments:

```
{
key1: value1,
key1_comment: "This is a comment for key1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is so-called [HJSON](https://hjson.github.io/) (Human JSON) which can have comments and other human-friendly features. And it has support in many popular languages.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/) question at StackOverflow regarding comments in JSON.