# Program can't find the config file, even though they're in the same folder

Tags: javascript, config

I'm trying to put some information into a config folder, but for some reason whenever I try to run index.js, i get this error:

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\eidhn\OneDrive\Desktop\dionysus\config.json: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
```

the relevant code is here:

```
// require the config file
const { prefix, token } = require(`./config.json`);
// require fs, node's native file system module
const fs = require('fs');
// require the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');
// create a discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();
// a class that extends the map() function
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
```

I've tried surrounding the ./config.json with single quotes, double quotes, or backticks, but nothing works.

They're right next to each other, in the same file, and i don't understand what's happening.

EDIT: this here is my json file

```
// storing data
{
    "prefix": "%",
    "token": "my token"
}
```

there is nothing else in the folder

EDIT: Thanks to commenters below, I didn't realise you couldn't use comments in `.json` files

Comment: those are not single quotes `'` they are called back ticks `\`` - try using single quotes in this part  `\`./config.json\`` instead?

Comment: @blurfus i've tried, these backticks were the last resort, and i copied and pasted to here right after trying them. single quotes were the very first thing i tried.

Comment: How does your `config.json` look like? Is it a properly formatted JSON file?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros i will update to show it, but i think so

Comment: JSON does not allow comments; does it? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json) - I think you need to remove the comments from the config file

Comment: @blurfus i had a quote at the start, i didn't realise that, thank you

Comment: @blurfus yeah, that did it. thanks a million

Comment: well, thank @ZsoltMeszaros as it was that comment that made it obvious to me :)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros write up an answer with your comment and my comment and earn the reputation points... :)

Comment: @blurfus Thanks, that's really generous, but your name is already mentioned in the post so feel free write up that answer ;)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros that can be fixed :)