# Add comment on the "manifest.json"

Tags: json, ide

I want to write a [chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/#manifest), so I need to write `manifest.json`, unfortunately, the IDE will not recognize the comments.

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json) said:

> It is a JSON-formatted file, with one exception: it is allowed to contain "//"-style comments.

So I am pretty sure added a comment for it is OK.

Is there any way to make the editor recognize the comments of `manifest.json`?

Comment: It seems that this self-answering question is not welcome, and I hope that those who voted against it can explain why. The first one who vote down that tells me, "Needs details or clarity."
I have already edited it, and then I got a negative vote again. I don't understand what the reason is for voting.
If this question is inappropriate, please leave a message, and I will delete the question.

Comment: I personally like your question. The "documentation" you refer to is from Mozilla though, so it could be different than what is allowed by Chrome extensions. However, even https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/ shows comments in manifest.json especially in the Manifest V3 examples. So it would be nice if someone could provide a documented/official answer about if comments are allowed in manifest.json files for Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the way as below,

```js
{
  "//1": "comment 1",
  "//2": "comment 2",
  "id": "123"
}
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44700108/9935654

But I think the best way is to change the `Recognized File Types` to the [json5](https://json5.org/)

[image]