# Adding comments to a JSON file

Tags: json, comments

Can you and what would be the best way to add comments to a JSON file?

I've used `//comments` and `"_comment"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, comments of the form `//…` or `/*…*/` are not allowed in JSON. This answer is based on:

- https://www.json.org
- RFC 4627: The application/json Media Type for JavaScript Object
  Notation (JSON)
- RFC 8259 The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange
  Format (supercedes RFCs 4627, 7158, 7159)

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183018/

Comment: This was plagiarized straight from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183018/ minus a few links.  Please don't copy content without attribution - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Comment: @Ollie, forgot that, my bad. Answer was updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cjson`. Use this utility to parse your json:
https://github.com/SubhenduShekhar/cjson

There are other features too.